# Can't login using Community Auth in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I've been following on how to install the Community Auth to codeigniter. I followed the instructions in the installation guide:

> 15 Create a user for testing purposes by editing the user_data array
>   that is inside the create_user method, which is in the Examples
>   controller. When specifying a user level, be aware of the
>   “levels_and_roles” array located in config/authentication. In order to
>   login in the next step the user level must be set to 9, which by
>   default is an admin. Also note that this method of user creation does
>   not account for password strength, yet the login validation does. A
>   password that is strong enough will have an uppercase letter, a
>   number, and be at least 8 characters long. Run /examples/create_user
>   in your browser to create the user.

However, I can't still login to it. It says that **LOGIN ERROR: Invalid Username, Email Address, or Password.**, always.

I already changed these:

```
            $user_data = array(
            'user_name'     => 'admin',
            'user_pass'     => 'admiN123',
            'user_email'    => 'admin@example.com',
            'user_level'    => '9', // 9 if you want to login @ examples/index.
        );
```

and use it to login but login error again and again.

Comment: I've never used CodeIgniter but have you tried changing the '9' for 9 (i.e. an int instead of a string?)

Comment: Still can't log in. @RobGudgeon

Answer (score 2):

Please activate the debugging information:

> Open up /application/config/config.php. Find the log_threshold setting
>   and change it to 2 or greater. 2 is the lowest level that allows for
>   debug level error messages to be logged, and this is the level that
>   Community Auth uses.

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

Read more on http://community-auth.com/documentation/debugging

Comment: "NO MATCH FOR USERNAME OR EMAIL DURING LOGIN ATTEMPT" I already changed the details on user_data and try to login using it but why am I getting this error? The database doesn't have any entries, and there is no instruction given that I should modify the database content. @ponsfrilus

Comment: Have you done the user creation as " Run /examples/create_user in your browser to create the user." ?

Comment: I don't know what happened but after i run it, the user I inserted in the $user_data was created. I could able to log in now!

Comment: I tried running it earlier but all I could get are guidelines about creating user. lol

Comment: Just saw that you say the database doesn't have any entries. On the installation process (http://community-auth.com/documentation/installation), step #14, you have to:
> 1. Create a database if not already available.
> 2. Run community_auth/sql/install.sql.
> 3. Configure CodeIgniter to use the database in config/database.php.

Comment: That's what i did. I followed all the process.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed, from using the debug, that my database password did not match the posted password.

When I had set my system up, I had not set up the `$config['encryption_key']` correctly.  So the fix was a simple as un-commenting the encryption_key...not sure why it was commented out to begin with.

The end fix was to set up my `/config/config.php` file to be:

```
 $config['encryption_key'] = '';
```